# Where can I download a tagged dataset of text related to finance, programming, analytics etc.?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, multiclass-classification

I want to create and train a model which classifies a new text content into finance, programming, analytics, design etc. Where can I get a relevant dataset to train my models?

TIA.

Comment: I believe, asking here http://opendata.stackexchange.com/ is better. Users on Open Data SE are more familiar with open data sets.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AnastasiosVentouris. Moving my question there.